# SendKeys from and to a locked computer

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I need to log on a computer via Remote Desktop, and execute some .Net things from that computer that requires SendKeys. The SendKeys work fine. However, if I break the remote connection, the SendKeys stop executing. I think it has to do with one of the limits with SendKeys that you can't SendKeys to a lock computer.

Anyone got an idea beside saying "SendKeys are bad, don't use it"?

Thanks